# AngularJS - ng-repeat not working when injected from a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to add "at runtime" in a directive an ng-repeat, and while the same ng-repeat work when put as an attribute in the html, it doesn't when added from a directive.  See the code and pluker below. NOTE: this is a very simplified version of the thing, but as you can see, the row are added (we wee 3 rows), but the value appear empty.  Thanks.

EDIT : I simplified the example to remove more possible noise from the experiment...

Obtained results:

LIST with ng-repeat as attribute

ITEM : A001

ITEM : A002

ITEM : A003

LIST with ng-repeat injected

ITEM :

ITEM :

ITEM :

[Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/GOJlu6KYwy82uxvsEmuR/)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 angular.module('rlfList', []);

 angular.module('rlfList').directive('rlfItem', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
  return {
   restrict: 'EA',
   scope: false,
   link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    if (!element.hasClass('rlfListRow')) {
     element.addClass('rlfListRow');
     element.attr('ng-repeat', 'item in records');
     $compile(element)(scope);
    }
   }
  };
 }]);

 angular.module('rlfList').controller('rlfController', ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
  
  $scope.records = [];
    
  $scope.records[0] = { number: 'A001' };
  $scope.records[1] = { number: 'A002' };
  $scope.records[2] = { number: 'A003' };

 }]);
</script>

<div ng-app="rlfList" ng-controller="rlfController">
      
      <div style="margin-top: 20px;">LIST with ng-repeat as attribute</div>
     <div ng-repeat="item in records"><span>ITEM : {{ item.number }}</span></div>

     <div style="margin-top: 20px;">LIST with ng-repeat injected</div>
     <div rlf-item><span>ITEM : {{ item.number }}</span></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: I think it is compiled as desired, but the element is never replaced. This can be the reason it's not working..

Answer (score 0):

When using property `scope : {}` in the directive definition object it create a new scope. So `rlfList` is not part of that new scope.

Change to `scope:false` so the directive uses its parent scope.

For more info on directive scope [here](https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/)

Comment: If the scope was not valid, it would not be able to count and display 3 rows. No ?  I mean, it's like it can count and display the the rows, but cannot access each object properties.  Still, I tryied what you say, and result is style not working (see new plunker : https://embed.plnkr.co/UsARAo2h95aZj7p0Wdvv/).  Thanks

Comment: remove `disabled-for-test-ng-repeat="item in rlfList.lists['listOne'].records"` and see the result. BTW what is `disabled-for-test-ng-repeat` for?

Comment: Good point about the disabled-for-test-ng-repeat="...  It was for testing purpose, but it was effectively doing something wrong... But **it still doesn't work**!  See my initial question, I edited/simplified it and remove anything not required and updated the plunker.